# Oracle Date Comparsion

Tags: sql, oracle, date-comparison

I have a column in TableA which contains date as Varchar2 datatype for column Start_date.( '2011-09-17:09:46:13').

Now what i need to do is , compare the Start_date of TableA with the SYSDATE, and list out any values thts atmost 7days older than SYSDATE.

Can any body help me with this isssue.

Comment: Use `Where to_date(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS')  between sysdate - 7 and sysdate;`

Comment: A date has both date and time elements. You have not mentioned whether you want to consider the time element or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perform the below to check the date:

```
select * from 
TableA
where
to_date(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') between sysdate and sysdate-7;
```

Comment: This is incorrect because you have not considered the time portion. A date has both date and time elements.

Comment: But I am only considering the date portion even though it contains the time  element.

Comment: Why? OP did not mention that. Neither did you mention anything. If you look at what op POSTED *Start_date.( '2011-09-17:09:46:13')* He is having both date and time elements. Your query will filter out those rows which fall outside the time for those days.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select * from tableA
where start_date between sysdate-7 and sysdate
```

Comment: `start_date` is varchar2 data type, yo must use **TO_DATE** to explicitly cconvert it into date first and then compare it with SYSDATE.

Comment: yeah spotted that a couple of mins ago, still annoys me when people store dates in varchar columns

Answer (score 1):

> I have a column in TableA which contains date as Varchar2 datatype for column Start_date.( '2011-09-17:09:46:13').

Then you have a flawed design. You must use appropriate data types for the data. A datetime should always be stored as **DATE** data type.

> Now what i need to do is , compare the Start_date of TableA with the SYSDATE, and list out any values thts atmost 7days older than SYSDATE.

Since the data type of your column is **VARCHAR2**, you must use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert the string into date.

```
where to_date(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') between sysdate and sysdate-7;
```

Remember, a **DATE** has both **date and time elements**. IF you want to ignore the time portion, then you need to use **TRUNC**.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2015-07-28 16:03:32

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)
-------------------
2015-07-28 00:00:00

SQL>
```

So, `BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate -7` will consider the current datetime till past 7 days till that time portion. If you only want to consider the date portion, use **TRUNC**.

For example,

```
where to_date(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') between TRUNC(sysdate) and TRUNC(sysdate-7);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you ought to be storing your times as DATE data types, you are at least storing the dates in a format that allows greater-than/less-than comparisons.

So, while you ought to convert these columns to dates, or alternatively convert the values to dates for comparison with SYSDATE -7, you could also convert SYSDATE -7 to the same string format as you are storing.

For example:

```
start_date between to_char(sysdate -7, "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS") and
                   to_char(sysdate   , "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS")
```

This would let you use an indexed search without needing a function-based index on the start date column.

Comment: Are you really suggesting to compare strings in place of dates? That would be so much annoying and confusing for someone who is analyzing the code. How would someone interpret the following string `2015-07-01`?  Is it `1st July`  or `7th Jan`?

Comment: It's a pragmatic approach. Usually you never would consider it because greater than or less than would not work for "01 Jul 1989" etc.. That date is definitely 1st July, because this is the ISO-8601 date format